# Passing method as function in Scala - conversion from Python

Tags: python, scala

In python can pass a function into a method like so :

```
def reducer:
   doStuff

run(reducer)
```

Is there a similar mechanism in Scala ? I could define a trait named reducer and implement a method. Then in run pass the name of the trait and then invoke the method ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, there is such thing:

```
def run(block: Unit => Unit) = {
  println("entering run")
  block()
  println("exiting run")
}

def block() = println("I'm block")

run(block)
// entering run
// I'm block
// exiting run
```

Note that you may need to change signature of run:

```
def run(f: Int => Int) {
  println("before call: 1, after call " + f(1))
}

def f(x: Int) = x + 1
run(f)
// before call: 1, after call 2
```

Comment: And just to add, it's not necessary to create `def block() = println("I'm block")` if the only thing you're doing is passing it in. It's perfectly valid to say `run(_ => println("I'm block"))` and cut out the middleman. (I'm sure you know this, but our OP may not)